# How to attach a UIButton to a segue originating from a different UIViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, segue

I've two UIViewControllers say A and B. And I've a segue from A to B which is being used by multiple buttons in A.

I've a use case where I want to give option to user to jump from B to B itself but to the next level of a game. You can think of it like A being level selection screen (Level 1, 2, 3, 4...and so on), and B being the game screen for level 1/2/3/4/etc.

When level 1 is finished, I want to give user a button with an option to jump to next level directly (i.e. same UIViewController with different data for the level). Can somebody suggest what's the best way to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should better subclass a baseGameViewController, which own your game scence needs common property, and every viewController has its own special feature.

Your post's meaning is impractical, because:

1. In storyboard, every ViewController interface only can have one ViewController Class.
2. If you use one ViewController to handle so many scence event and data, it is complex, and also it is not accord with design model.